# Trouble understanding on how to calculate all possible events of sample space S

Tags: statistics

While doing some exercises I had following question:

How many possible events can be defined if the sample space S looks as follows:

- $S = \{1,2,3\}  $
- $S = \{1,2,3,4\}  $
- $S = \{s_1, ..., s_n\}$

The solution is $8$, $16$, $2^n$.

Can someone explain me why the solution is $2^n$?

Comment: Any subset of the (finite) sample space is an event. You can look up or figure out how to see that the number of subsets of an $n$ element set is $2^n$,

Comment: How would you get the answers $8=2^3$ or $16=2^4$? This is not difficult to generalize.

Comment: @Arthur The thing is, I don't get how the solution is e.g. 8.

Comment: Then I suggest you start there. List all possible options. Try to be systematic. Then count them. Try to be clever about the counting, so that counting hundreds or thousands isn't much more work than counting the 8 you have this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You can count the events. The sample space $S$ contains $n$ possible outcomes. What is the event space at the first case?

It is $\{\emptyset,1,2,3,12,13,23,123\}$. $\emptyset$ is the empty set (Never forget it!). It constains $2^3=8$ events. If you say that $k$ is the number of elements of a sequence then it can be written as a sum: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}=2^n$.

Answer (score 3):

I think it’s because each number in the sample space is either part of the event or not, which is two possibilities. So with the three numbers 1, 2 and 3, there are 2 x 2 x 2 possibilities which is 2$^3$ This is then generalized with n numbers to 2$^n$

Answer (score 0):

If the set has $n$ elements, then you are looking for the number $2^n$.

If you know some combinatorics, it follows from:

Let $S$ the sample space with $n$ elements

total events: all individual events + all combinations of 2 events + all combinatinations of 3 events + .. + all combination of $n-1$ events + all combinations of $n$ events (only 1 comb.)

- all individual events: this is the combinatoric of $n$ in $1$
- all combinations of 2 events: this is the combinatoric of $n$ in $2$ 
  -all combinations of 3 events: this is the combinatoric of $n$ in $3$
- ...

So you need the number :

$${{n}\choose{0}}+{n\choose{1}}+{n\choose{2}}+{n\choose{3}}+\cdots+{n\choose{n-1}}+{n\choose{n}}=2^n$$